# how to get airflow DAG execution date using command line?

Tags: airflow

In order for me to get the dag_state, I run the following LCI command:

```
airflow dag_state  example_bash_operator '12-12T16:04:46.960661+00:00'
```

The trouble is - I have to explicitly pass the exact date-time (i.e. execution_date) to this command.
When I run `airflow list_dags` I only get a listing of DAG's but not their execution dates.

Is there a way to obtain the exact date time `(i.e. -> '12-12T16:04:46.960661+00:00')`

for a given dag, using command line CLI?

Answer (score 1):

There's a conceptual issue here. `Dag`s are objects that have schedules, not execution dates. When the schedule is due, `DagRun`s are created for that `Dag` with the appropriate `execution_date`.

So you can ask for the state of a `DagRun` using the CLI and providing the `execution_date`, because execution dates (almost uniquely) map to a specific `DagRun`. Almost uniquely because in practice you can trigger two `DagRun`s with the same `execution_date`, but that's an unusual scenario.

But if you ask for the `execution_date` of a `Dag`, what do you *really* want to know? The `execution_date` of the last recently created `DagRun`? The list of `execution_date`s for the currently running `DagRun`s?

You can check [`list_dag_runs`](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#list_dag_runs)`dag_id` CLI command and see if yon can filter it to your needs.